# notepad++ open textfile with selfdefined language via console

Tags: bash, console, notepad++

Like said above I want to open a text-file with a User-Defined highlighting via bash-script.

```
notepad++ -n$1 -lmyLanguage myfile.dat
```

if I use prebuild lanuages like xml or bash it works fine like

```
notepad++ -n12 -lxml myfile.dat
```

but with my self-deffined language-set its not working. Is it due to where the languages are stored? do i have to move some files?

### EDIT:

As far as I found out, its not possible in the conventional way (see answer below). If someone finds a workaround (i.e. maybe altering witht the xml-files) I would be a happy man!

Answer (score 0):

You can definie what syntax should be used for an extension of a file. That can be done by lut in UserLang tag atrribute ext.  Try to Look at sample Lang for example sas.

Comment: The extension is working fine if i open the file via doubleclick. If i open it via the shell, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible yet.
User-Manual sais:

```
-llanguage short name
    Language to set for each file opened. $$$ is a short identifier string,
    of which the following are allowed:

normal, php, c, cpp, cs, objc, d, java, rc, html, xml, makefile,
pascal, batch, ini, nfo, asp, sql, vb, javascript, css, perl, python, 
lua, tex, cobol, fortran, bash, actionscript, nsis, tcl, lisp, scheme,
asm, diff, props, postscript, ruby, smalltalk, vhdl, kix, autoit, 
Gui4Cli, powershell, caml, ada, verilog, matlab, haskell, inno, cmake, yaml,r, jsp
```